# Slow wifi after with Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak]

Tags: intel-wireless

After upgrading from kubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 suddenly my wifi connection is very slow. Ping times are varying from 200 up to 1500 ms to www.google.nl.

When I connect my ethernet cable they drop to normal times like 8 or 9 ms. Anyone experiencing the same problem or know a solution I can try? During the upgrade process a few times they asked whether I wanted to keep or replace some kind of configuration file. I'm not sure anymore which file it was, but maybe this has something to do with it. Before the upgrade both wired and wireless connection worked perfect.

```
***** uname -a *****

Linux K53SV 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

***** lsb_release *****

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:    13.10
Codename:   saucy

***** lspci *****

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] [8086:008a] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 BGN [8086:5305]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1277]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

***** lsusb *****

Bus 002 Device 008: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 for Business
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 1532:000d Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 045e:0761 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 03f0:7611 Hewlett-Packard DeskJet F2492 All-in-One
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:a014 Alcor Micro Corp. Asus Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 8086:0189 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


***** iwconfig *****

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Linksys"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: <MAC address removed>   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-32 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:3  Invalid misc:24617   Missed beacon:0



***** lsmod *****

iwldvm                237440  0 
mac80211              596969  1 iwldvm
iwlwifi               165398  1 iwldvm
cfg80211              479757  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm

***** nm-tool *****

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off


- Device: wlan0  [Linksys] -----------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           1 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    *Linksys:        Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 88 WPA2
    Yo-Chris-Yo:     Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 39 WPA2
    Sitecom0210C8:   Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 49 WPA2
    Sitecom72DE64:   Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 60 WPA2
    Fonera:          Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 49 WPA2
    FON_FREE_INTERNET: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 50
    Uilenstede/ACTA/Rijssen: Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2472 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 44 WPA2
    SparKalme:       Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 24 WPA WPA2
    EikRijke:        Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2457 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 WPA WPA2
    Chan:            Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 32 WPA WPA2
    dedriekoffertjes:Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 34 WPA2
    TP-LINK_EFA49A:  Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 24 WPA2
    Sitecom6C4844:   Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 29 WPA2
    SKJ:             Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 32 WPA2
    Guess who...:    Infra, <MAC address removed>, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 19 WPA WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.111
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1



***** NetworkManager.state *****
[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

***** NetworkManager.conf *****

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

***** interfaces *****

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

***** iwlist *****

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-31 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Linksys"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000001c97005a91
                    Extra: Last beacon: 16ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00074C696E6B737973
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AFC181BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1606081500000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180202F0040000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=21/70  Signal level=-89 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"SparKalme"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000029f2c6dc5
                    Extra: Last beacon: 5544ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0009537061724B616C6D65
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A7C181BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601001300000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD740050F204104A0001101044000102103B0001031047001085F64238A1415DE70DCB4F68E34271B0102100074C696E6B73797310230004453930301024000776312E302E30331042000234321054000800060050F20400011011000445393030100800022688103C0001011049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180201F0280000
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=30/70  Signal level=-80 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Fonera"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000207b024ba
                    Extra: Last beacon: 16ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0006466F6E657261
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A6C0117FF000000000000000000000000000000000C0000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601000400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3E0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: 0B05010031127A
                    IE: Unknown: 7F0101
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4304000000
                    IE: Unknown: 07064E4C20010D10
                    IE: Unknown: DD9D0050F204104A0001101044000102103B000103104700102880288028801880A8800018842CFC8C1021001852616C696E6B20546563686E6F6C6F67792C20436F72702E1023001C52616C696E6B20576972656C6573732041636365737320506F696E74102400065254323836301042000831323334353637381054000800060050F20400011011000952616C696E6B415053100800020084103C000101
          Cell 04 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=38/70  Signal level=-72 dBm  
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"FON_FREE_INTERNET"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s
                              18 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000207b04858
                    Extra: Last beacon: 16ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0011464F4E5F465245455F494E5445524E4554
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B961224486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0104
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C183060
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A6C0117FF000000000000000000000000000000000C0000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601000400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3E0100
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                    IE: Unknown: 0B05010031127A
                    IE: Unknown: 7F0101
                    IE: Unknown: DD07000C4304000000
                    IE: Unknown: 07064E4C20010D10
          Cell 05 - Address: <MAC address removed>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=21/70  Signal level=-89 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Chan"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000015f4ffaeb
                    Extra: Last beacon: 7144ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 00044368616E
                    IE: Unknown: 010882848B962430486C
                    IE: Unknown: 030101
                    IE: Unknown: 050400010000
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A7C181BFFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1601001700000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F204104A00011010440001021049000600372A000120
                    IE: Unknown: DD090010180203F0280000
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK


***** modinfo *****

filename:       /lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/iwldvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2013 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     189D6366522149BFF40DA25
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.11.0-12-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 

filename:       /lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2013 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
srcversion:     B3EF32124305F5D1F6E94A5
```

Full information: http://pastebin.com/spui8HSz

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the contents of the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.  No internet then go to this link for running the script without internet.
[url]http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12350385[/url]

Comment: Thanks for your reply and wonderful script Wild Man. I took a look into it, and wished that I could script like that. Anyway, here is the link you requested: http://pastebin.com/spui8HSz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do:

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv iwldvm
sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi
sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi
```

Go into network manager and change your wireless settings to match the screenshots.

[image: wireless settings][image: wireless settings]

Go into your router and change 802.11bgn to 802.11bg then save the settings and reboot router and computer.

Lets modify this file:
    sudo /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
change

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

To:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0
```

Comment: Well, that seems to solve the problem for a moment. Now it works sometimes, but sometimes it's still very slow even to the point where there is no connection at all.

Comment: Some drivers have problems with N speeds and the commands disable N speed and allow the driver to operate much faster and more reliable.

Comment: Please read my edit in first reply, it is working better now. But still not optimal.

Comment: Make sure your wired connection is unplugged then test your wireless. Wired connection always overrides wireless, and I believe your wired connection will be slow because it is using the wrong driver.

Comment: I have my wired connection unplugged during testing. Speed becomes very slow, ping times are varying from 8 ms up to 500 ms. This is an improvement, because before the alterations you gave me, there were none normal ping times (8-10 ms). But it's still not very workable.

Comment: Follow the directions in my answer from Edit down. Thanks

Comment: I've followed the directions, tested wireless for some longer period and it seemes to work fine now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: i did this is it has done wonders, my internet connection is way faster now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I updated to 14.04. I tried everything also answers from this post. After a while I thought that I will give a try to LM, it turn out that problem disappeared and the magic is in linux-firmware package. LM uses the old version which is 1.127 whereas Ubuntu uses now 1.127.7. The easiest way to restore it to this version is: install Synaptic, find this package, click on it to mark it, press Ctrl+E and change its version. Apply changes and problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by downgrading my kernel version.

Comment: This answer is incomplete at best. You downgraded your kernel to what version and how? Answers should be as complete as possible to insure that even those unfamiliar with the process can follow your steps and succeed. Thank you.